# Parse GUID out of string with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, guid

In my website I have a textbox where the user will enter a GUID from a promo code.
I would like to automatically add hyphens to the string that the user enters manually or via copy/paste.
This should be done via jQuery or jQuery or maybe there is a HTML5 solution as well?

I've found a solution for a creditcard number, which is not that far away from the solution I am searching for. But as I am not experienced with RegEx I cannot get it to work for a GUID.

User @jmp came up with another idea, that works in general, but looks ... not that nice. Cause when you start entering your code your value looks like "123-----". It would be nice if the string changes dynamically like in sample 1 (credit card)

This is what I have so far:

```js
$('.creditCardText').keyup(function() {
  var foo1 = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
  if (foo1.length > 0) {
    foo1 = foo1.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join("-");    
  }
  $(this).val(foo1);
});


$('.guidText').keyup(function() {
  var foo2 = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
  if (foo2.length > 0) {
    foo2 = new String().concat(foo2.substring(0,8), '-', foo2.substring(8,12), '-', foo2.substring(12,16), '-', foo2.substring(16,20), '-', foo2.substring(20,32));
  }
  $(this).val(foo2);
});
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
    width: 350px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Creditcard pattern:<br />
<input type="text" class="creditCardText" placeholder="1234-5678-1111-0000" maxlength="19"/>

<br/><br/>

GUID Pattern:<br />
<input type="text" class="guidText" placeholder="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" maxlength="36"/>
```

PS: I am not allowed to use external plugins or scripts

Comment: why not do something like this in plain old javascript? `newVal = new String().concat(GUID.substring(0,4), '-', GUID.substring(4,8), '-', GUID.substring(8,13))`

Comment: works - but looks awful :-D When you enter 111 you're getting 111-----

Comment: the question should be updated with this then

Comment: you're right, done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your working GUID mask using jquery inputmask bundle.

```js
$( () => {
  $("#cc").inputmask({"mask": "99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999"});
});
```

```css
input {
  font-family: monospace;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
div {
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<form action="">
  
  <div>
    <label for="cc">GUID</label>
    <!-- Set via HTML -->
    <input id="cc" type="text" data-inputmask="'mask': '99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999'" />
  </div>
  
</form>
```

Okay here is one I made, without any plugin.

```js
const el = document.getElementById("in");

el.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) return;

  const arr = e.target.value.split("");
  const digitsNum = [8, 4, 4, 4, 12];

  let count = 0;
  let index = 0;
  let ret = "";

  for (let digit of arr) {
    if(typeof digitsNum[index] === 'undefined') continue;

    count++;

    ret += digit!= "-" ? digit : "";

    if(typeof digitsNum[index] !== 'undefined')
    if (count >= digitsNum[index]) {
      count = -1;
      index++;
      ret += "-";
    }
    
  }

  e.target.value = ret;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in" />
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that I am not allowed to use a plugin .. :-(

Comment: So maybe something like this? https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/ObOzeM

Comment: that given sample uses 2 plugins :-(

Comment: I have found this sample to detect a GUID with RegEx. But I cannot get it to work with my sample: https://www.regextester.com/94410

Comment: @JonSnow Sample you found is to split same sized numbers. I edited my answer to fit your needs now.

Comment: The new sample is pretty close! But yeah, as it is a GUID I need to allow characters as well :-/

Comment: Saw your latest edit: that's PERFECT, you're my star of the day! Thank you so much for your help. i would never have solved it on my own... have a great weekend my friend!